# Can't access local network resources from a specific access point

Tags: router, home-networking, home-server

I've got two wireless routers in my home; one came with my internet service and is also the modem for the service. I also have another setup for extra range. I've connected the second (a d-link wireless-n) via a cat5 wire attached directly to the other modem using one of the switch ports (not the WAN port), and set it up so that its ip is on the same subnet as the first: My main router is 192.168.2.1, and the second is 192.168.2.2. I also made sure to disable the DHCP server and other services that it provides.

I can connect to the internet via any of the two devices without issue, but some of my internal services like my calibre ebook server and other servers on my PC can only be accessed  via my phone when I am connected to one of the routers... And this is the strange part: The router that my PC is wired into is not the router that I'm connected to via wifi. The wifi connection via the router that my PC is hooked to does not give me access to my server. I can't even ping it by IP using an app on my phone; I have the following message:

From 192.168.2.12 to 192.168.2.254: Destination Host Unreachable. Through my other router (again, not the one my PC is connected to), I can't get a ping response, but at least it just times out.

I've got only one subnet (192.168.2.0/24) and only one DHCP server, so it shouldn't be a matter of routing. I have absolutely no idea where to look?